# matplotlib.patches Circle - transparent?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

How to make the circle clear transparent? The desired result is a black edge and None colour to see the plots behind the circle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                 # 3d graph
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d                 # 3d graph
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d, art3d  
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

# Plot figure
figsize=[5,5]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.azim = -57   # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 29     # x rotation (default=0)

# Set limits
ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim(-50, 50)

R = 50
floor_front = Circle((0, 0), R, linewidth=2, edgecolor = 'black', alpha = 0.3)   # (x, z), radius
ax.add_patch(floor_front)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(floor_front, z=0, zdir="y")        # z = corresponds to y 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Circle(), add `facecolor="none"`.

[image: facecolor_none]